# Using Fragments inside of Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am using 4 fragments in MainActivity with viewPager where viewPager is not scrollable, and I have four more fragments inside Second Fragment of MainActivity fragment. I am calling API in my all fragments in the onCreateView method. But when activity initialized so all fragments onCreateView method run, how to fix it because I want when the fragment is visible than my API call.

I already tried setUserVisibleHint method it's also working when activity initialized.

Should I use frame layout or anything else to fix this problem?

Comment: When `setVisibility` is called, are you checking the parameter `visibleToUser`? It should be true for the currently visible fragment, and false for the others.

Comment: I checked but isVisibleToUser boolean get true for all fragment when activity set fragment adapter.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you good then you want to call your api when fragments are visible.

if yes then use

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener
```

and onPageSelected(int position) callback then just make good condition which call you'r api

edit: changed adapter to viewPager

Comment: I am using FragmentPagerAdapter and can't find addonPageChangeListener method.
Do you mean viewPager.addOnPagerChangeListener.

Comment: yes ofcourse that was my bad and im sorry :) its adapter method inkotlin its         mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{})

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your api calls method in **onResume** in each fragment that will be fired when your fragment is on the top of fragments stack (Shown).

Comment: Then what should i do if i don't want to load all fragments are together.